# cellular network not working in iPhone 4S after update of iOS 8

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, cellular-data

I have iPhone 4S was working perfectly on iOS 7.0.1. After updating to 8.1.2, cellular networks fail often on my iPhone 4S.

I've performed these steps:

- restore it from iTunes
- downgraded to 8.1.1 and 8.1 (While that sign iOS is available) but still its not working.
- reset network settings
- restart the phone
- correct the date on the phone and enter Airplane mode / verify the correct time / exit Airplane mode

The WiFi works continuously - but resetting

I am thinking of to jailbreak it if it resolve the issue. but before that i would like to know if there is any other possible solution to that?

**Update:** I have remove SIM card then update date time for the iPhone. Then restarted it. Then insert SIM card it shows me list of available network in the carrier manual settings. I have selected my carrier and it shows me network after 5 mins. But during that process it was connected to iTunes with PC. After sometimes, it lost network. I have try same thing without connecting to the iTunes, at that time it is not working.

So, whenever i connect with itunes in PC and do same process, it works. But after few minutes, it lost the network.

I am not able to identify where is the problem. Please help me argent for same.

I am not sure, it is related to hardware or software, but i guess it is related to software only, because if it related to hardware then it will not work even once with the mention trick.

**Another Update:** 
I have try once and it works up to some hours. I have connect the iPhone with iTunes with laptop. Then remove sim card. Reset Network setting. Change date-time and then restart it again then insert SIM card, then select my network manually from the list. Now it shows network but it remaing till my iPhone connected to itunes. Once it disconnected from the iTunes and i check it will not remain network for long time. Every time i do this trick and it have network but not for much time. What is wrong with my iPhone?

Comment: There might be an issue with your SIM card. Can you try with the SIM of a friend (or contact the carrier directly for a replacement card)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have try with two different card. I am having same problem in both. If i enter same sim card in another iPhone, it works fine. So there is no problem with sim card.

Comment: @patrix I have try once and it works up to some hours. I have connect the iPhone with iTunes with laptop. Then remove sim card. Reset Network setting. Change date-time and then restart it again then insert SIM card, then select my network manually from the list. Now it shows network but it remaing till my iPhone connected to itunes. Once it disconnected from the iTunes and i check it will not remain network for long time. Every time i do this trick and it have network but not for much time. What is wrong with my iPhone?